# Android code using Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I access the Android Java code, created by the Titanium as a result of the Titanium development?

Comment: It comes all precompiled with the SDKs. I think you'd have to get a fork off the GitHub project and compile it yourself once you've made the changes. I was trying to do this yesterday but have no idea how to compile it https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile

Answer (score 1):

You don't have such a possibility since all the javascript code in Titanium is interpreted by a JavaScript engine internally and `.class` files are generated.

Follow [this](http://titaniumninja.com/post/10559549700/fastdev-for-ios-how-it-works/) link for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the interpretation of your javascript code, then you can't. Everything is turned into symbols for Titanium to interpret, but you can find this at your /build folder

Answer (score 0):

Titanium use javascript code, Modules let you write code in a platform's native language (Java for Android)， Titanium can use java native code in  [module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide) and java code run in v8 。